# AppleScript Finder "can't get disk" from selection

Tags: finder, applescript, error, disk-volume

I used to have a script to open files one at a time, then manipulate them, then close them. I haven't used it in a while, but now it does not work when I use it in a NAS directory. It breaks when I try to open the files that were selected in Finder:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set theSelection to selection
    repeat with oneItem in theSelection
        open oneItem
    end repeat
end tell
```

when it tries to open the file, I get

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t get disk "foo"." number -1728 from disk "foo"

the location of the file is

```
//NAS/foo/bar/file.pages
```

I have tried:

- hard code the location in applescript
- mount the disk manually in applescript first
- change the location to `"/Volumes/foo/bar/file.pages"` and different versions of that like `document file file.pages of folder bar of folder foo of folder Volumes of startup disk`
- on my local machine it works fine
- when I ask applescript to `get selection` it replies with the correct location

when I try to use /Volumes I get the same error but for "can't find folder Volumes"

This used to work fine...and it seems like a pretty straightforward task for AppleScript/Finder...any thoughts?

Comment: Testing in **macOS Catalina** with a _network volume_ mounted at `/Volumes/Data/` and with files selected in **Finder** it opened the files just fine, however, you might want to try changing `set theSelection to selection` to `set theSelection to selection as alias list` and see if that makes any difference for you. **Note:** I also tested with getting rid of the `repeat` _loop_ and just used `open theSelection` after `set theSelection to selection as alias list` within the `tell` _block_ for **Finder**, and it too worked for me without issue.

Comment: @user3439894 I've been testing by just trying to open locations directly without the loop, etc. When I use `open ("/Volumes/foo/bar" as POSIX file)` it works fine. But when I use `open folder "foo" of folder "Volumes" of startup disk` it does not.

Comment: RE: "But when I use `open folder "foo" of folder "Volumes" of startup disk` it does not." --  Which is exactly why I suggested you use `set theSelection to selection as alias list`, and as I said, I had no issue.

Comment: @user3439894 sorry my reply wasn't complete. I accidentally submitted it but then timed out while writing so couldn't post the edit. I tried using your alias suggestion, but also didn't work. I got a similar message "Can’t get alias \"foo:bar:\"." number -1728"

Comment: Just curious, what version of **macOS** are you running?

Comment: @user3439894 I'm running Catalina. The last time I ran this script I think was before Catalina.

Comment: In **Terminal**, what is the output of: `ls -leO@d /Volumes/foo`